# Upload documents to Buddypress activities without Groups

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, plugins, android-activity, buddypress

A PHP/js developer called Stergatu has developed an awesome Buddypress plugin that allows users to upload documents as activity attachments. I want to use it to develop a file sharing site. It's very good but it has one restriction. The user must be in a group in order to upload documents.

Here is my comment on her blog - http://lenasterg.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/buddypress-group-documents-for-bp-1-7-and-wp-3-5-1/#comment-426

I was wondering if any of you would be able to help me is she cannot.

Ideally, not being in a group would be an option in the Worpress admin panel. This seems like a natural progression for the development of this plugin.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I think the answer is really simply for a PHP expert. Just a standard file upload and URL insertion into the activity stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BuddyDrive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/buddydrive/) plugin

Here is [more info.](http://wpmu.org/create-a-dropbox-clone-with-buddypress-and-buddydrive/)

Comment: The BuddyDrive and Group Documents plugins do more than I require. I don't need anything that sophisticated. I simply need users to be able to upload documents at the same time as updating their activity status, and have the document URL inserted into the activity status as a hyperlink.